# How can I create multiple files using chef recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I wanted to create the loop using 'each' but I couldn't. When I looked at the examples using 'each', array was always used. Is there a solution using while or for?

```
while $i <=  do

  file "/home/user/files/file_#{i}" do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
  $i +=1
end
```

I want it to look like this
`file_1 file_2 file_3 ...`

Comment: `file "/home/user/files/file_#{i}" do` missing `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`times` or `range`](https://www.rubyguides.com/ruby-tutorial/loops/) methods instead of `while`.

Example using range:

```rb
(1..5).each do |i|
  file "/home/user/files/file_#{i}" do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

Here I'm using range of `(1..5)`, which will create `file_1` to `file_5`. You can change it to the numbers with which the files should be created.